# How to get a fixed blurry effect on top-bottom browser window when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

How to get a blurry effect fixed on the top and bottom extremities of a browser window. So when you scroll, you see the elements on the page getting blurred as you go up or down the page. Please have a look at this example: goo.gl/MOIdF2

Is there a jQuery plugin available or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Here I extracted the css code from that page for you or anyone who want to know about it:

On the main wrapper, could be `body` tag or any element that wrap the whole page, put these css codes. Make sure that you add vendor specific prefixes for `linear-gradient` (see the reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)):

```
#your_wrapper:before {
    background: linear-gradient(center top , #fff 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 60%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 300px;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#your_wrapper:after {
    background: linear-gradient(center bottom , #fff 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 60%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 300px;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

#your_wrapper {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 200px;
  padding-left: 102px;
  padding-top: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Wroked flaswlessly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the example that you provided, they've applied a CSS gradient (solid white to transparent) to a `:before` pseudo element, which they've then positioned over top of the text. You could do the same thing, but replace the gradient with a CSS blur filter, like this:

```
.blurry {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Please note that CSS filters are relatively new, and are not yet supported by Internet Explorer. [Here's some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter#blur()_2) and [here are some examples](http://bennettfeely.com/filters/).

You could use Javascript to add the blur effect when the user begins to scroll, then remove the blur effect after a short timeout, like this:

```
<script>
  var timer;
  $(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    // Apply blur filter to your elements by adding a class
    $('.your-element').addClass('blurry');
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(onScrollEnd, 1000);
  });
  function onScrollEnd() {
    // Remove blur filter from your elements by removing a class
    $('.your-element').removeClass('blurry');
    console.log('Stopped Scrolling'); 
  }
</script>
```